# Swift. How to create Segue from custom CollectionViewCell to .xib File (ViewController), by programmatically maybe?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

How to create **Segue** from custom **CollectionViewCell** to **.xib File** (ViewController, is a Player), by programmatically maybe?

I do have main **ViewController** on Storyboard but almost all components i made by code. And also have xib file - **PlayerViewController**.

In the main **ViewController** I have **CollectionView** with **custom cell**.

And on tap on any cell I need to push Data (**Video** object) to **PlayerViewController**.

If by Segue, how can I create Segue identifier by Code?
Or on storyboard but without “drag-and-connect”

Comment: You can create Segue between UIViewController in a Storyboard to another Storyboard or another UIViewController in that storyboard. If you have a xib, you either need to use a Storyboard for it, or do it the old way: initialize the PlayerViewController with its xib, and pass the property needed, and present it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need segue you can pass data programmatically like this.

Let suppose your **XIB** and **controller** name is same.

```
let controller =  YourViewController()
controller.data = yourdatta
self.navigationController.push(controller)
```

Comment: Big thanks! I will return to this project within a week. If questions come up, I will write it here

Comment: If answer was helpful then you can accept it by clicking the Tick mark. Thank you.